# TLS 1.3 clarification needed on hello_hash and subsequent hashes

Tags: hash, tls, sha-256

I am exploring TLS, mainly from the server side at the moment. I am creating a server that will authenticate a client using TLS 1.3 and eventually I will be creating a client authenticating to a server. It is not intended for production, but merely for learning.

I am having a few question regarding the hashes, from what I understand **hello_hash** (used to calculate the handshake traffic secrets) would be :

```
Sha256( ClientHello[5:end] + ServerHello[5:end] )
```

and **verify_hash** (the one used to sign the certificate verification) would be :

```
Sha256( ClientHello[5:end] + ServerHello[5:end] + EncryptedExtensions[all] + Certificate[all] )
```

I am not sure if the 5 bytes record should be included in the **verify_hash**? We are excluding the ones from ClientHello and ServerHello, so I assumed that we should exclude this one as well?

and the **handshake_hash** (the one used to calculate the application traffic secrets) would be :

```
Sha256( ClientHello[5:end] + ServerHello[5:end] + EncryptedExtensions[all] + Certificate[all] + CertificateVerify[all] + HandshakeFinished[all] )
```

Again I am not sure if the record that encapsulate EncryptedExtensions, Certificate, CertificateVerify and HandshakeFinished should be included in this one, the documentation isn't very clear about this.

Finally, from the client side will the hash be the exact same as these ones? I mean the same order? I assume that they are as they probably need to match to create the matching keys and ivs